# how do I use autotools with relative directories for GitLab jobs?

Tags: gitlab, autotools

I'm trying to use GNU autotools to configure, make, and install a program. I'm running into problems when I configure and make the program inside a GitLab job. It builds without errors, the problem is when I try to run the binary I built in the test jobs it errors out saying the binary doesn't exist because the config file still has the absolute path from the build job? Can I update the config.h without recompiling? I just need to be able to use the binary without errors?

Comment: The `config.h` file generated by `configure` is used (only) while building the program.  Modifying it after the build is complete will not affect the behavior of the program.

Comment: The Autotools have a variety of features supporting building software for installation in a particular place and for testing it in the (usually different) build location, but we have no way to advise you on specifics.  If you present a [mre] representative of your issue then we can give specific advice.

Comment: Have you specified the executable as artifact or are you building and running the program in the same stage?